# How Mange Memory to solve NotEnoughMemoryException in C#

Tags: c#, memory-management

My memory is 4GB(2.99GB usable, but I don't know why).
When use Bluebit Library to deal with Matrix in project C# Visual Studio 2010, and when  execute code in Windows Form Application and after connect with Database, appear NotEnoughMemoryException (There is not enough memory to continue the execution) and physically memory used is 2.14GB , but when use code alone in Console Application doesn't appear any exception.

```
StreamWriter aWr = new StreamWriter("aMatrix.mtx");
Matrix aMatrix = new Matrix(termsList.Count, Docs.Count);
/////load aMatrix from DataBase and aMatrix[8200, 40]

SVD svd = new SVD(aMatrix);
StreamWriter sWr = new StreamWriter("sMatrix.mtx");
Matrix S = svd.S.SubMatrix(0, k - 1, 0, k - 1);
for (int row = 0; row < S.Rows; row++)
{
        for (int col = 0; col < S.Cols; col++)
            sWr.Write(S[row, col] + "\t");
        sWr.Write("\n");
}
sWr.Close();

StreamWriter uWr = new StreamWriter("uMatrix.mtx");
Matrix U = svd.U;
nt endRaws = U.Rows - 1;
U = U.SubMatrix(0, endRaws, 0, k - 1);
for (int row = 0; row < U.Rows; row++)                                                      
{
    for (int col = 0; col < U.Cols; col++)
        uWr.Write(U[row, col] + "\t");
    uWr.Write("\n");
}
uWr.Close();

StreamWriter vWr = new StreamWriter("vMatrix.mtx");
Matrix V = svd.V;
endRaws = V.Rows - 1;
V = V.SubMatrix(0, endRaws, 0, k - 1);
for (int row = 0; row < V.Rows; row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < V.Cols; col++)
        vWr.Write(V[row, col] + "\t");
    vWr.Write("\n");
}
vWr.Close();

StreamWriter vtWr = new StreamWriter("vtMatrix.mtx");
Matrix VT = new Matrix(V.Cols, V.Rows);
for (int row = 0; row < V.Rows; row++)
    for (int col = 0; col < V.Cols; col++)
        VT[col, row] = V[row, col];

for (int row = 0; row < VT.Rows; row++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < VT.Cols; col++)
        vtWr.Write(VT[row, col] + "\t");
    vtWr.Write("\n");
}
vtWr.Close();
```

How I can Manage my Memory?

Comment: How much data is in the .mtx files?

Comment: That's not a FCL exception - what exactly is throwing it?

Comment: The [NotEnoughMemoryException Class](http://www.bluebit.gr/NET/Library/topic736.html) is part of the Bluebit Matrix Library.

Comment: aMatrix.mtx: 1.34MB
other files doesn't created

Comment: Your operating system's probably going to use a noticeable portion of that 4GB, at least if it's Windows.

Comment: when i execute 2.14GB from 2.99GB

Comment: And you run this on a 32 bit windows? You need 64 bits.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build your app in x64 mode to use more than 2Gb per process, see [Why am I getting an Out Of Memory Exception in my C# application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/597499/1070291)