# Out of memory exception C# List

Tags: c#, list, out-of-memory

How should I make a list which can accommodate this range(in the code) since it is showing out of memory exception?

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var l1 = Enumerable.Range(999900000, 1000000000).ToList();
            l1.ForEach(f => Console.WriteLine(f));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you running 32 bit or a 64 bit version?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why am I getting an Out Of Memory Exception in my C# application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597499/why-am-i-getting-an-out-of-memory-exception-in-my-c-sharp-application)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't convert to `List<T>`, just enumerate:

```
var l1 = Enumerable.Range(999900000, 1000000000);
foreach(var f in l1)
    Console.WriteLine(f);
```

Comment: Exactly what lazy evaluation was made for :-)

Answer (score 2):

Do not collect all data you need in the list especially if you know already the content of it,  but use *enumerator*, to reduce in this way memory footprint of your app.

For example:

```
    IEnumerable<int> GetNextInt()
    {
        for(int i=999900000; i< 1000000000; i++)
        {
            yield return i;
        }
    }
```

and use this after in loop like

```
foreach(var integer in GetNextInt())
{ 
    //do something.. 
}
```